# positive weights and negative weights

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array named as weights -

```
array([-0.11387602,  0.07744348, -0.25294052,  0.06635546,  0.11452402,
    0.02732373, -0.09838084, -0.06822771,  0.06360016,  0.36889096,
    0.0232971 , -0.2113415 ,  0.38389924, -0.21285646, -0.03606946,
    0.03405694, -0.16547289,  0.07334644,  0.057695  ,  0.05680166,
   -0.14985729, -0.1537674 ,  0.06515446,  0.13564594, -0.07660504,
   -0.22963317, -0.27253672, -0.14489202, -0.05152282, -0.0773859 ,
    0.01486651, -0.10037556, -0.0162965 , -0.01810175, -0.09474796,
    0.35913295, -0.290787  ])
```

I am trying for hours to get an array where the output is normalized for positives and for negative. LOGIC - positive number divide by all positive numbers in the array AND negative number divide by sum of all negative numbers in the array.

in the end the output of the operation should show positives weight (which adds to 1) and negative weights (which adds to -1).

Please help :)

PS: using python

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try:

```
pos = np.where(x>=0,x,0).sum(0)
neg = np.where(x<0,x,0).sum(0)

y = np.where(x>=0, x/pos, -x/neg)
```

OR

```
y = np.where(x>=0, x/x[x>=0].sum(), -x/x[x<0].sum())
```

**y:**

```
array([-0.04015835,  0.04029246, -0.08919942,  0.03452356,  0.0595848 ,
        0.01421605, -0.03469398, -0.02406049,  0.03309003,  0.19192738,
        0.01212107, -0.07452953,  0.19973592, -0.07506378, -0.01271989,
        0.01771922, -0.05835398,  0.03816084,  0.03001768,  0.02955289,
       -0.05284714, -0.05422604,  0.0338987 ,  0.07057416, -0.02701475,
       -0.08098009, -0.09611001, -0.05109614, -0.01816951, -0.02729012,
        0.00773478, -0.03539742, -0.00574696, -0.00638358, -0.03341285,
        0.18685046, -0.10254597])
```

---

`y[y>=0].sum()`  ---> `0.9999999999999999`

`y[y<0].sum()`   ---> `-1.0000000000000002`

Comment: I think that OP is after maintaining negative values as negative (negative weights), so that the entire array sums to 0.

Comment: I have updated my answer just need to add - sign

Comment: Thank You! Pygirl! that is one elegant code. Great one liner :-)

Answer (score 0):

1. Let me first import `numpy` as `np` and define the array you set:

```py
import numpy as np
a = np.array([-0.11387602,  0.07744348, -0.25294052,  0.06635546,  0.11452402,
    0.02732373, -0.09838084, -0.06822771,  0.06360016,  0.36889096,
    0.0232971 , -0.2113415 ,  0.38389924, -0.21285646, -0.03606946,
    0.03405694, -0.16547289,  0.07334644,  0.057695  ,  0.05680166,
   -0.14985729, -0.1537674 ,  0.06515446,  0.13564594, -0.07660504,
   -0.22963317, -0.27253672, -0.14489202, -0.05152282, -0.0773859 ,
    0.01486651, -0.10037556, -0.0162965 , -0.01810175, -0.09474796,
    0.35913295, -0.290787  ])
```

2. Then use list comprehension (`[x for x in list]`) with condition (`[x for x in list if condition]`). Finally, take average by numpy mean function with `np.mean`.

2a) Positive weights:

```py
np.mean([x for x in a if x>0])
```

2b) Negative weights:

```py
np.mean([x for x in a if x<0])
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do is to import this as a numpy array, in case that hasn't yet been done:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([-0.11387602,  0.07744348, -0.25294052,  0.06635546,  0.11452402,
    0.02732373, -0.09838084, -0.06822771,  0.06360016,  0.36889096,
    0.0232971 , -0.2113415 ,  0.38389924, -0.21285646, -0.03606946,
    0.03405694, -0.16547289,  0.07334644,  0.057695  ,  0.05680166,
   -0.14985729, -0.1537674 ,  0.06515446,  0.13564594, -0.07660504,
   -0.22963317, -0.27253672, -0.14489202, -0.05152282, -0.0773859 ,
    0.01486651, -0.10037556, -0.0162965 , -0.01810175, -0.09474796,
    0.35913295, -0.290787 ])
```

Thereafter, you can use indexing to search for negative or positive values, as follows:

```
a[a < 0] 
a[a >= 0]
```

Using this, you can assign all values to be divided by the sum of all positive or negative values:

```
a[a>=0] = (a[a >= 0])/(a[a >= 0].sum())
a[a<0] = -1*(a[a < 0])/(a[a < 0].sum())
```

Note that for the negative values, we need to multiply by -1 to maintain the sign of the negatives.

We can confirm we've reached your objective by summing the values:

```
(a[a < 0].sum()) OUTPUT: -1.0000000000000002
(a[a > 0].sum()) OUTPUT: 0.9999999999999999
```

Note: if you are trying to do this as part of an ongoing programme, you may wish to do some error checking (such as ensuring the sum does not equal zero, which would cause the error of division by 0).

Comment: np.sum(a) will give you the expected result of nearly 0.

Answer (score 0):

please clarify this statement "positive number divide by all positive numbers in the array"

Here is how you can do it, first of all, because you have a 1d array you cand do it in o(n) first you need your numbers, iterate through your array, and find the Sum of negatives and whatever you want for positives.

then in the for you should go through your array, and do the division operation, and adding the values 1 or -1.

I would code it for you but I think it would be better if you code it yourself